# Targets don't match node IDs in networkx json file

Tags: python, networkx

I have a network I want to output to a json file.  However, when I output it, node targets become converted to numbers and do not match the node ids which are strings.

For example:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(data)
G.edges()
```

results in:

```
[(22, 'str1'),
(22, 'str2'),
(22, 'str3')]
```

in python.  This is correct.

But in the output, when I write out the data like so...

```
json.dump(json_graph.node_link_data(G), f, 
          indent = 4, sort_keys = True, separators=(',',':'))
```

while the ids for the three target nodes 'str1', 'str2', and 'str3'...

```
{
    "id":"str1"
},
{
    "id":"str2"
},
{
    "id":"str3"
}
```

The targets of node 22 have been turned into numbers

```
    {
        "source":22,
        "target":972
    },
    {
        "source":22,
        "target":1261
    },
    {
        "source":22,
        "target":1259
    }
```

This happens for all nodes that have string ids

Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

The desired result is that either "target" fields should keep the string ids, or that the string ids become numeric in a way that they match the targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this

It's a feature. Not all graph libraries accept strings as identifiers, but all that I know of accept integers.

> how can I prevent it?

Replace the ids by node names using the `nodes` map:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import pprint
>>> g = nx.DiGraph()
>>> g.add_edge(1, 'foo')
>>> g.add_edge(2, 'bar')
>>> g.add_edge('foo', 'bar')
>>> res = nx.node_link_data(g)
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
{'directed': True,
 'graph': {},
 'links': [{'source': 0, 'target': 3},
           {'source': 1, 'target': 2},
           {'source': 3, 'target': 2}],
 'multigraph': False,
 'nodes': [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}, {'name': 'bar'}, {'name': 'foo'}]}
>>> res['links'] = [
        {
            'source': res['nodes'][link['source']]['name'],
            'target': res['nodes'][link['target']]['name']
        }
        for link in res['links']]
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
{'directed': True,
 'graph': {},
 'links': [{'source': 1, 'target': 'foo'},
           {'source': 2, 'target': 'bar'},
           {'source': 'foo', 'target': 'bar'}],
 'multigraph': False,
 'nodes': [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}, {'name': 'bar'}, {'name': 'foo'}]}
```

Comment: Ah interesting, it seems like if strings are replaced by numbers for link targets and sources, then so should the id values - otherwise how would a library know from the output json data what a node is linking to?  I guess I'm new to networkx and graphs so all the issues involved are not clear to me.

Nevertheless, thanks for the answer and how to access and modify this data :)

Comment: What do you mean by “id values”? integer node names? They are replaced as well. For instance, in the `links` array, `'source': 0` refers to node 0, which is named 1.

Comment: I mean that when I write out the data using the json_graph.node_link_data, it will make keys like 'nodes' and 'links'.  Under 'nodes' the replacement does not occur, only under 'links'.  But I guess like you say all of the unique 'source' values would be equivalent to the list of nodes that need connections, so it can work that way if the software reading the data just ignores the 'nodes' key and just uses the 'source' data.

Answer (score 0):

To make the output conform to the d3 template that is linked in the node_link_data documentation, you can make a couple simple changes to the node_link_data function. Just run the below function and use it instead. All I changed was to trim some of the unnecessary outputs for the template, and to store the graph label instead of an index. The index the original function used for target and destination was created in the function, so it isn't something you can extract from the graph itself, so if you want to be certain that your node labels correspond to your links, it's safest to modify node_link_data.

[The D3 Template this creates data for is here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

Note that if you use the below data without adding a node or link attribute, you will need to delete the following lines from the d3 template:

```
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
```

and

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

Modified function:

```
from itertools import chain, count
import json
import networkx as nx
from networkx.utils import make_str
__author__ = """Aric Hagberg <hagberg@lanl.gov>"""
_attrs = dict(id='id', source='source', target='target', key='key')

def node_link_data(G, attrs=_attrs):
    """Return data in node-link format that is suitable for JSON serialization
    and use in Javascript documents.
    """
    multigraph = G.is_multigraph()
    id_ = attrs['id']
    source = attrs['source']
    target = attrs['target']
    # Allow 'key' to be omitted from attrs if the graph is not a multigraph.
    key = None if not multigraph else attrs['key']
    if len(set([source, target, key])) < 3:
        raise nx.NetworkXError('Attribute names are not unique.')
    mapping = dict(zip(G, count()))
    data = {}
    data['nodes'] = [dict(chain(G.node[n].items(), [(id_, n)])) for n in G]
    if multigraph:
        data['links'] = [
            dict(chain(d.items(),
                       [(source, u), (target,v), (key, k)]))
            for u, v, k, d in G.edges_iter(keys=True, data=True)]
    else:
        data['links'] = [
            dict(chain(d.items(),
                       [(source, u), (target, v)]))
            for u, v, d in G.edges_iter(data=True)]
    return data
```